# How to combine CSS Grid and ::before / ::after?

Tags: html, css, animation, css-grid

Basically I try to style a CSS grid and one of the features I want to implement is a rotating gradient as border.

I use the ::before and ::after pseudo-elements thereto.

I managed to implement it as a standalone but as soon as I add it to one of the grid cells it does not show anything. Want am I doing wrong?

Here is a minimal example:

```css
:root {
  --main-radius: 30px;
  --main-padding: 20px;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  height: 97vh;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "content1 content2 content3";
  grid-gap: 2rem;
  color: #004d40;
  text-align: center;
}

@property --rotate {
  syntax: "<angle>";
  initial-value: 132deg;
  inherits: false;
}

#content1 {
  background: #6fffd2;
  grid-area: content1;
  border-radius: var(--main-radius);
  padding-top: var(--main-padding);
}

.content1::before {
  content: "";
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
  border-radius: var(--main-radius);
  background-image: linear-gradient( var(--rotate), #5ddcff, #3c67e3 43%, #4e00c2);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: -1%;
  left: -2%;
  animation: spin 2.5s linear infinite;
}

.content1::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 20px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transform: scale(0.8);
  filter: blur(20px);
  background-image: linear-gradient( var(--rotate), #5ddcff, #3c67e3 43%, #4e00c2);
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s;
  animation: spin 2.5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    --rotate: 0deg;
  }
  100% {
    --rotate: 360deg;
  }
}

#content2 {
  background: #64ffda;
  grid-area: content2;
  border-radius: var(--main-radius);
  padding-top: var(--main-padding);
}

#content3 {
  background: #73ffba;
  grid-area: content3;
  border-radius: var(--main-radius);
  padding-top: var(--main-padding);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="content1">Content 1</div>
  <div id="content2">Content2</div>
  <div id="content3">Content3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: In the example you gave us, you are adding the pseudo element on the **class** content1 which does not exist, you only got an ```id="content1"```.

Comment: Thank you! This is indeed where my mistake was to find...

Comment: No worrys, happens to us all ;)